# Radeon developer panel not detecting running program

Tags: linux, gpu, profiling, vulkan, amd-processor

I have a vulkan application I want to profile (to find the bottlenecks on the gpu for optimizations). I am on linux and amd hardware so I downloaded the linux version of the radeon developer tools. I ran it and created a local server and that seems to work.

I then launched my program, but it does not appear on the list of profiling candidates in the panel.

[image]

As you can see the connection is fine (green dot), but no applications are detected. I have tried with advanced mode as well but no luck.

I know for a fact the program is running as I can see it and use it, recompile it... Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Dumb question but is your Vulkan application definitely using the Radeon GPU? (it might be using an integrated GPU instead)

Comment: It is using an integrated gpu, but the processor is AMD. The exact string returned by vulkaninfo is: ` deviceName     = AMD RADV RAVEN2 (ACO)`